# How can you set a floor to the gaussian decay function in ElasticSearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to use Elastic Search for storing geo spatial data. However I want the relevance score to be a combination of the distance from a point and the relevance based on text matching queries. For example, lets say that the query is `Yellowstone National Park`, but the origin is in Chicago. `Portage Park` in Chicago is more likely to match because for any reasonable distance and decay because `Yellowstone National Park` will have a decay score close to zero and won't show up in the results at all. What I'd like to do is to have a FLOOR on the decay score, so that beyond a certain distance, all results look the same.

For example, here's the Java code I have:

```
      queryBuilder = new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder(queryBuilder).add(
      ScoreFunctionBuilders.gaussDecayFunction("search_geo_point", point.get(), "10km")
          .setDecay(0.75)
          .setOffset("5km"));
```

What I'd like to do is treat all points that are greater than say 30km from the origin as identical, and have the decay function no longer reduce the score beyond that point. Is this possible? The problem is that beyond a certain distance the decay function reduces the relevance so much that even if the query is an exact match for a text field, it does not appear in the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a feature implemented within function score in Elasticsearch, although it would be very handy.

However, you can achieve your goal with a small workaround by using the filter clauses in the [function query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-weight):

```
POST test/parks/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "name": "Yellowstone National park"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "gauss": {
            "location": {
              "origin": "41.4881832, -87.623177",
              "scale": "10km",
              "offset": "5km"
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "geo_distance_range": {
              "from": "0km",
              "to": "30km",
              "location": {
                "lat": 41.881832,
                "lon": -87.623177
              },
              "include_upper": false
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "weight": ## Set appropriate weight,
          "filter": {
            "geo_distance_range": {
              "from": "30km",
              "location": {
                "lat": 41.881832,
                "lon": -87.623177
              },
              "include_lower": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

With the query above, you only apply the gauss function score to hits within the range of 30km. In the second filter clause, you define a constant score for all hits, which are further afar. 
Note that you should set include_upper and include_lower appropriately to prevent scoring the same element multiple times.